# Why my logistic regression always predict value near 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to write a logistic regression with L1 regularization.I use stochastic gradient ascend of log-likelihood as the cost function. But my function always give out values that near 0. My dataset is from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/HTRU2

Here is the example, where y_hat is the output of the predict function and y[i] is the true value of the target:

```
y_hat: [ 0.08707034] y[i]: 0
y_hat - y[i]: [ 0.08707034]
y_hat: [ 0.06406335] y[i]: 0
y_hat - y[i]: [ 0.06406335]
y_hat: [ 0.04818193] y[i]: 0
y_hat - y[i]: [ 0.04818193]
y_hat: [ 0.19760354] y[i]: 1
y_hat - y[i]: [-0.80239646]
y_hat: [ 0.08982549] y[i]: 0
y_hat - y[i]: [ 0.08982549]
y_hat: [ 0.0844086] y[i]: 1
y_hat - y[i]: [-0.9155914]
```

And here is the accuracy when the threshold is 0.5

```
threshold= 0.5
acc= 0.0159217877095
```

and here is my logistic sgd code

```
def logreg_sgd(X, y, alpha = .001, iters = 100000, eps=1e-4):
    n, d = X.shape
    theta = numpy.zeros((d, 1))
    k = 0
    lam = 0.001

    for k in range(iters):
        i = k%n
        x = X[i, :]
        xT = numpy.transpose([x])
        y_hat = sigmoid(x, theta)
        beta = de_norm1(theta)

        func_g = (y[i] - y_hat)*xT + lam*beta

        theta_k = theta.copy()
        theta = theta + alpha*func_g
        for delta in abs(theta-theta_k):
            if delta > eps:
                break

    return theta

def de_norm1(theta):
    d, _ = theta.shape
    beta = numpy.zeros((d, 1))

    for i in range(d):
        if theta[i,0] < 0:
            beta[i,0] = -1
        elif theta[i,0] > 0:
            beta[i,0] = 1
    return beta

def sigmoid(X, theta):
    z = numpy.dot(X, theta)
    value = 1.0/(1.0 + numpy.exp(-z))
    return value
```

I can not figure out why it is wrong

**Below is the second edit content.**

here is the roc_curve I draw.

[roc curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyNwb.png)

and the code to draw roc cureve

```
# plot the ROC curve of your prediction
# x aixes: TPR = TP / ( TP + FN )
# y aixes: FPR = FP / ( FP + TN ) 
def plot_roc_curve(X_test, y_true, theta):
    k = 51
    FPR_x = numpy.zeros(k)
    TPR_y = numpy.zeros(k)

    for n in range(k):
        threshold = n/(k-1)
        y_pred, FPR, TPR = predict(X_test, y_true, theta, threshold)
        tn, fp, fn, tp = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
        FPR_x[n] = fp/(fp+tn)
        TPR_y[n] = tp/(tp+fn)
        print(FPR_x[n], TPR_y[n])

    plt.xlabel('FPR')
    plt.ylabel('TPR')
    plt.plot(FPR_x, TPR_y, '-')
    # plt.scatter(FPR_x, TPR_y, marker='o', color='blue')
    plt.show()
```

Here is the predict(classify) fuction

```
def predict(X, y_true, theta, threshold):
    value = sigmoid(X, theta)
    row, col = X.shape
    y_hat = numpy.zeros(row)
    P = sum(y_true)
    N = row - P
    FP = 0.0
    TP = 0.0
    print('P =', P)

    for i, val in enumerate(value):
        if val > threshold:
            y_hat[i] = 1
            TP+=1
        else:
            y_hat[i] = 0
        if y_true[i] != y_hat[i]:
            if y_true[i] == 0:
                FP+=1
    FPR = FP/N
    TPR = TP/P
    return y_hat, FPR, TPR
```

my data load function

```
def load_train_test_data(train_ratio=.8):
    data = pandas.read_csv('./HTRU2/HTRU_2.csv', header=None)

    X = data.iloc[:,:8]
    X = numpy.concatenate((numpy.ones((len(X), 1)), X), axis=1)
    y = data.iloc[:,8]
    y = numpy.array(y)
    return sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1 - train_ratio, random_state=0)
```

The scale function

```
def scale_features(X_train, X_test, low=0, upp=1):
    minmax_scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(low, upp)).fit(numpy.vstack((X_train, X_test)))
    X_train_scale = minmax_scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_test_scale = minmax_scaler.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_scale, X_test_scale
```

my main function

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

import numpy
import pandas
import sklearn.metrics
import sklearn.model_selection
import sklearn.linear_model
import sklearn.preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main(argv):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = load_train_test_data(train_ratio=.8)
        X_train_scale, X_test_scale = scale_features(X_train, X_test, 0, 1)

        theta = logreg_sgd(X_train_scale, y_train)
        print('theta:\n', theta)
        plot_roc_curve(X_test, y_test, theta)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

sample data:

```
140.5625,55.68378214,-0.234571412,-0.699648398,3.199832776,19.11042633,7.975531794,74.24222492,0
102.5078125,58.88243001,0.465318154,-0.515087909,1.677257525,14.86014572,10.57648674,127.3935796,0
103.015625,39.34164944,0.323328365,1.051164429,3.121237458,21.74466875,7.735822015,63.17190911,0
136.75,57.17844874,-0.068414638,-0.636238369,3.642976589,20.9592803,6.89649891,53.59366067,0
88.7265625,40.67222541,0.600866079,1.123491692,1.178929766,11.4687196,14.26957284,252.5673058,0
93.5703125,46.69811352,0.53190485,0.416721117,1.636287625,14.54507425,10.6217484,131.3940043,0
119.484375,48.76505927,0.03146022,-0.112167573,0.99916388,9.279612239,19.20623018,479.7565669,0
130.3828125,39.84405561,-0.158322759,0.389540448,1.220735786,14.37894124,13.53945602,198.2364565,0
107.25,52.62707834,0.452688025,0.170347382,2.331939799,14.48685311,9.001004441,107.9725056,0
107.2578125,39.49648839,0.465881961,1.162877124,4.079431438,24.98041798,7.397079948,57.78473789,0
142.078125,45.28807262,-0.320328426,0.283952506,5.376254181,29.00989748,6.076265849,37.83139335,0
133.2578125,44.05824378,-0.081059862,0.115361506,1.632107023,12.00780568,11.97206663,195.5434476,0
134.9609375,49.55432662,-0.135303833,-0.080469602,10.69648829,41.34204361,3.893934139,14.13120625,0
117.9453125,45.50657724,0.325437564,0.661459458,2.836120401,23.11834971,8.943211912,82.47559187,0
138.1796875,51.5244835,-0.031852329,0.046797173,6.330267559,31.57634673,5.155939859,26.14331017,0
114.3671875,51.94571552,-0.094498904,-0.287984087,2.738294314,17.19189079,9.050612454,96.61190318,0
109.640625,49.01765217,0.13763583,-0.256699775,1.508361204,12.07290134,13.36792556,223.4384192,0
100.8515625,51.74352161,0.393836792,-0.011240741,2.841137124,21.63577754,8.302241891,71.58436903,0
136.09375,51.69100464,-0.045908926,-0.271816393,9.342809365,38.09639955,4.345438138,18.67364854,0
99.3671875,41.57220208,1.547196967,4.154106043,27.55518395,61.71901588,2.20880796,3.662680136,1
100.890625,51.89039446,0.627486528,-0.026497802,3.883779264,23.04526673,6.953167635,52.27944038,0
105.4453125,41.13996851,0.142653801,0.320419676,3.551839465,20.75501684,7.739552295,68.51977061,0
95.8671875,42.05992212,0.326386917,0.803501794,1.83277592,12.24896949,11.249331,177.2307712,0
117.3671875,53.90861351,0.257953441,-0.405049077,6.018394649,24.76612335,4.807783224,25.52261561,0
106.6484375,56.36718209,0.378355072,-0.266371607,2.43645485,18.40537062,9.378659682,96.86022536,0
112.71875,50.3012701,0.279390953,-0.129010712,8.281772575,37.81001224,4.691826852,21.27620977,0
130.8515625,52.43285734,0.142596727,0.018885442,2.64632107,15.65443599,9.464164025,115.6731586,0
119.4375,52.87481531,-0.002549267,-0.460360287,2.365384615,16.49803188,9.008351898,94.75565692,0
123.2109375,51.07801208,0.179376819,-0.17728516,2.107023411,16.92177312,10.08033334,112.5585913,0
102.6171875,49.69235371,0.230438984,0.193325371,1.489130435,16.00441146,12.64653474,171.8329021,0
110.109375,41.31816988,0.094860398,0.68311261,1.010033445,13.02627521,14.66651082,231.2041363,0
99.9140625,43.91949797,0.475728501,0.781486196,0.619565217,9.440975862,20.1066391,475.680218,0
128.34375,52.17210664,-0.049280401,-0.208256987,2.173913043,12.9939472,9.965757364,141.5100843,0
142.0546875,53.87315957,-0.470772686,-0.125946417,4.423076923,27.08351266,6.681658306,45.94403008,0
121.1328125,47.6326062,0.177360308,0.024918111,2.151337793,20.55243738,9.920468181,99.74707919,0
102.328125,48.98040255,0.315729409,-0.202183315,1.898829431,13.83904002,11.61993869,172.1303732,0
147.8359375,53.62263651,-0.131079596,-0.288851172,2.692307692,17.08088101,8.849177975,92.20174502,0
108.0390625,34.91024257,0.321156562,1.821631493,3.899665552,23.72205203,7.506209958,60.88691267,0
107.875,37.33065932,0.49600476,1.481815856,1.173913043,12.01691346,14.53428973,252.6947381,0
118.84375,45.9319193,-0.109242666,0.137683548,2.33277592,14.71602871,9.634175054,118.6696797,0
138.4609375,48.91716569,-0.039591916,-0.176243068,2.443143813,18.3133067,8.672894053,83.06924213,0
116.203125,47.34586165,0.211946824,-0.022177703,3.606187291,18.94498977,7.035644684,59.23122572,0
120.5546875,45.54990543,0.282923998,0.419908714,1.358695652,13.07903424,13.31214143,212.5970294,1
121.8828125,53.04267461,0.200520721,-0.282219034,2.116220736,16.58087621,8.947602793,91.01176155,0
125.2109375,51.17519729,0.139851288,-0.385736754,1.147993311,12.41401211,14.06879728,228.1315536,0
107.90625,48.08414459,0.460846577,0.29651005,1.993311037,13.84106954,9.969395408,128.7447168,0
106.28125,43.02178545,0.408868006,1.032014666,1.610367893,17.25115554,12.11019331,152.0149562,0
106.3359375,45.05002035,0.418645099,0.603995884,1.200668896,12.38856143,13.30645184,209.41199,0
125.734375,52.65772207,0.026516673,-0.429632907,4.850334448,29.93619483,6.361837308,40.25501275,0
113.546875,49.50029346,0.130001201,-0.202839025,2.407190635,14.42205142,9.310343318,113.6874714,0
134.0390625,51.80045885,-0.195844789,-0.396816077,1.107859532,13.23858397,13.77580037,208.4202575,0
105.1171875,45.09202762,0.464847891,0.878058377,4.283444816,23.96731526,6.562543005,46.66728734,0
95.328125,44.66789069,0.386495074,0.755115427,2.694816054,17.9985973,9.094177089,97.80243629,0
119.3359375,47.506953,0.220316758,0.645717725,0.79264214,9.540907141,18.76653977,441.5133427,0
136.1875,51.95291588,-0.070431774,-0.482219687,0.849498328,9.677531027,18.73655411,431.3904454,0
112.859375,55.10625168,0.174766173,-0.404019163,3.032608696,19.69431374,7.266252257,58.03777067,0
108.625,52.74614915,0.453556415,0.069731528,2.304347826,16.18365586,9.780440566,114.9993838,0
113.953125,49.2214161,0.234723211,0.289792216,1.081103679,13.48209307,14.25608113,216.8362204,0
141.96875,50.47089779,0.244974491,-0.342664657,2.823578595,16.23818776,8.207743613,85.53258352,0
136.5,49.9327673,0.044623267,-0.374311456,1.555183946,12.81353792,13.31433912,214.813089,0
83.6796875,36.37928102,0.572531753,2.66461052,4.0409699,23.16912864,7.006681423,53.51400467,0
27.765625,28.66604164,5.770087392,37.4190088,73.11287625,62.07021971,1.268206006,1.082920221,1
135.859375,51.93727202,0.065768774,-0.366114187,20.77424749,52.77264803,2.730908619,6.607439551,0
112.09375,48.81156969,0.418565459,0.350156301,2.204013378,17.37868175,9.520551079,100.7875964,0
126.8671875,53.1293191,0.13633915,-0.588709439,1.149665552,13.96514443,13.23049959,186.2685104,0
117.5390625,47.73296528,0.173139263,-0.150653604,1.060200669,14.28934355,14.17637248,208.2780851,0
143.0859375,49.92197464,-0.157561213,-0.153332697,3.563545151,21.28808157,7.337117054,59.16844081,0
101.296875,39.43395574,0.390053688,1.551969375,4.925585284,26.32242163,6.086053659,39.11620774,0
119.8984375,53.82550508,0.143378486,-0.528427658,4.04180602,24.57913147,6.581293412,44.89951492,0
123.125,50.33124651,-0.087091427,0.087932382,1.280936455,10.68864639,14.63669101,288.668932,0
102.046875,48.79050551,0.45222638,0.272447732,2.37541806,13.9284014,9.127499454,116.0232222,0
119.4453125,53.14305702,0.012830273,-0.378955989,2.932274247,17.9297569,8.289888515,81.34651657,0
128.515625,54.94585181,-0.012552759,-0.658278628,2.891304348,17.75294666,8.913745414,94.08210337,0
128.15625,46.89690113,-0.179233074,-0.005819915,4.193979933,22.25815766,6.451755484,46.48663173,0
115.6171875,40.29037592,0.110702345,0.513224267,11.63963211,39.95655753,3.640288988,12.68457562,0
136.7421875,44.39123754,-0.22192524,0.908084632,2.105351171,14.49837742,10.13157115,128.3951486,0
135.265625,48.14390609,0.015920939,-0.15877212,8.539297659,31.13487695,4.082788387,17.27267344,0
113.9609375,52.24736871,0.127976811,-0.457499415,4.407190635,26.29776588,6.709564866,47.4057088,0
107.796875,45.6803362,0.655279783,0.954879021,1.7090301,15.1907807,11.52025038,150.3053634,0
124.5,57.35361802,-0.014849043,-0.550963937,4.783444816,27.50164045,6.090448645,37.81809112,0
119.296875,46.45417086,0.202629139,0.12837064,3.748327759,18.8510099,6.414682286,50.85055687,0
148.3828125,51.200757,-0.113195798,-0.50223559,1.408026756,12.08791939,12.5121354,201.1278905,0
109.4921875,53.2901838,0.2528458,-0.319022964,4.132943144,25.89210734,6.741542034,46.83080307,0
112.125,46.30840906,0.721646098,0.612454163,1.173076923,11.04918969,14.6307442,273.2509626,0
128.7734375,45.80669555,0.086169154,-0.031764808,2.66722408,15.93295829,8.75667197,95.36727143,0
140.265625,48.93721813,0.03252958,0.119064502,2.315217391,19.87317992,9.67260138,98.89698457,0
87.515625,51.76343189,1.070588903,0.74283956,15.67809365,50.90591579,3.141187931,8.440045483,0
132.140625,42.09582342,0.143191723,0.876730035,1.863712375,13.26595667,10.25798651,140.0407088,0
104.078125,45.24078107,0.532040422,0.743853067,1.43645485,15.41478275,11.89911604,150.9872549,0
122.6015625,53.79697654,-0.051964773,-0.379729027,2.636287625,15.17095406,9.519292364,117.7422254,0
114.28125,41.25396525,0.41182113,0.616996141,2.412207358,20.42794216,9.198391753,88.37057957,0
112.4375,38.2956733,0.501943444,1.07484029,2.81270903,18.13688307,7.859968426,71.29944944,0
23.625,29.94865398,5.688038235,35.98717152,146.5685619,82.39462399,-0.274901598,-1.121848281,1
94.5859375,35.77982308,1.187308683,3.68746932,6.071070234,29.76039993,5.318766827,28.69804799,1
137.2421875,46.45474042,0.045257133,-0.438857507,59.4958194,77.75535652,0.71974817,-1.183162032,0
123.53125,53.34878418,0.072077648,-0.071600995,0.781772575,10.57083301,17.11829958,339.6608262,0
70.0234375,35.28067478,1.157657193,4.546692371,3.003344482,19.57538355,7.954436097,71.96015886,0
129.375,44.56841651,0.049779493,0.506330188,3.60451505,21.13303805,7.181384025,56.85662961,0
97.140625,47.77089438,0.625218075,0.740796144,4.193143813,26.46526062,6.927045631,49.62852693,0
101.96875,46.31632702,0.439814307,0.294261355,1.748327759,16.4866229,10.8103928,127.7333664,0
```

Comment: What is your accuracy? I mean assuming you do your binary classification assigning to class 0 if y_hat < 0.5 and to class 1 if y_hat > 0.5, what results do you get? In your post you show only some examples, but it could well be that those are ok. What are the results for _all_ the observations? Or you mean you get _always_ zero?

Comment: Another question, assuming your X is your input vector, why don't you have a constant term when you calculate ```z``` in your sigmoid? The so called bias?

Comment: the first column of X is set as a constant, 1, so I think the first weight in the theta array would be the constant weight.

Comment: can you please add the entire code on how you call your functions? And it would be nice to have a small dataset to test your code.  But to start with, the entire code would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. I checked your data set. You have a _very_ unbalanced data set. You have 98 points and only 5 that are labelled as 1. So your model will naturally tend to predict everything as zero. Your best bet would be to try to get more data. Ideally you would need a balanced dataset, with the same number of observation labelled as zero and the one. I would try (just to see what happens) what your model tells you if you take only 10 observations: the 5 labelled as 1 and 5 at random labelled as zero. I will try to test your code later.

Comment: And another comment... You realize that with your line ```return sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1 - train_ratio, random_state=0``` you may well end up with a training set containing only zero labelled observation right? That may also be the source why your model labels everything as zero. **EDIT**: I checked and you actually get 4 of your observations that are labelled as 1. Still a very unbalanced dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I will use an answer since in comments I don't have enough space. I hope to point you in the right direction. You can use sklearn to get values to check your model against. I downloaded your dataset and created (in a quick and dirty way) a balanced dataset

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = 
   sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(data, labels, 
   test_size = 1 - 0.8, random_state=0)
X_train_bal1 = X_train[y_train == 1]
Y_train1 = y_train[y_train == 1]

X_train_bal0 = X_train[y_train == 0].sample(len(X_train_bal1))
Y_train0 = y_train[y_train == 0].sample(len(X_train_bal1))

X = pd.concat([X_train_bal1, X_train_bal0])
Y = pd.concat([Y_train1, Y_train0])
```

Then I used sklearn to perform a logistic regression

```
logisticb = LogisticRegression()
logisticb.fit(X,Y)

logisticb.score(X,Y)
```

Now you have 1365 observations labelled as 1 and 1365 observations labelled as 0. You get an score of 0.943. So pretty good. In your original dataset you are dealing with roughly 1% of observations labelled as 1 against roughly 99% labelled as 0. I am checking your code as I am typing this. Will update this answer as soon as I find out what is wrong.

**EDIT**: I checked your code, but I must admit that I would simply simplify it and I would rewrite it. For what you want to do (logistic regression) is overly complicated and difficult to debug. I think that you better invest the time you would need to debug the code in simplyfing it.

On a positive note I applaud you for trying to implement logistic regression from scratch. It is a wonderful learning experience. You are doing many things right (like scaling the input X). Something you should try is to vectorize your code as much as you can using numpy features. Your code is quite slow. You can make it really fast. If you it can help you I wrote a complete implementation of logistic regression from scratch and is available from github (https://github.com/michelucci/Logistic-Regression-Explained/blob/master/MNIST%20with%20Logistic%20Regression%20from%20scratch.ipynb). Maybe it can help you.

Good luck and all the best, Umberto

Comment: Thank you! I will check it.

Comment: Good luck. And let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think my code do the right steps in logistic regression, there seems to appear bugs in my code. My problem have not solve yet, but you wrote a great tutorial! It is clear and detail.